# Check Permissions does not list all permissions on site

Tags: 2010, permissions

In Site Settings, Site Permissions, Check Permissions it tells me user A has Read access given through group X. IGroup X has Contribute to certain parts of the site, why is this not listed on the Check Permissions dialogue box? I know Read is the default for this group but almost everything on this site does not inherit permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check permissions only checks the permissions of the current object that you invoked Check permissions on.

For example:

- If you do Check Permissions on the site, it will detail how a user has site level access only.
- If you do it on a document library, it will detail how the user has access to the document library only.
- If you do it on a file, it will detail how the user has permissions to the file.

If you need comprehensive permissions reporting on the site as a whole, you will need to write something to do that, or use third party tools to do so.

Comment: Oh that's disapointing, I assumed accessing it from Site Settings would give me an overview. Good to know